# How to set button onclick event in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically create a `div` for each user's campaign.

What I'd really like to see is a "show details" button inside the `div` that redirects to the campaign details. I tried to run this code, but it only takes the last index.

```
for (var i = utente.campagne.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var appended = document.createElement("DIV");
  appended.className = "jumbotron";
  var nome = document.createElement("p");
  nome.innerHTML = "Campaign Name: " + utente.campagne[i].nome;
  appended.appendChild(nome);
  var button = document.createElement("INPUT");
  button.type = "button";
  var index = i;
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.location = "ShowDetails.jsp?indexcampagna=" + index;
  });

  button.value = "show details";
  button.className = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
  appended.appendChild(button);
  var col = document.createElement("DIV");
  col.className = "col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center";
  col.appendChild(appended);
  document.getElementById("boxes").appendChild(col);
}
```

Comment: use let i  instead of var i in the for declaration. let has block level scope and var has function level scope..

Comment: Please do not use the `java` tag if you are not using java. javascript != java

Comment: removed unrelated tags, fixed title, fixed code formatting. Spelling + grammar